# Project structure changed after Maven update project, Inclusion and exclusion patterns to source folder changed too

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-3, spring-tool-suite

This is the project structure developed initially:

```
src/
src/main/java
    com.company.project.module1.bean
    com.company.project.module1.controller
    com.company.project.module1.service
    com.company.project.module1.dao
src/main/resources
src/test/
src/test/resources
```

After clicking Maven --> "Update Project" for the project the complete project structure is changed as below:

```
src/
    com.company.project.module1.bean
    com.company.project.module1.controller
    com.company.project.module1.service
    com.company.project.module1.dao
src/main/java
    com.company.project.module1.bean
    com.company.project.module1.controller
    com.company.project.module1.service
    com.company.project.module1.dao
src/main/resources
src/test/
src/test/resources
```

All java class files where "copied" into src/ folder.

When I checked in project properties these are the configuration found at "Java Build Path" --> "source"--> src/:

Before "Update Project" through Maven configuration:

```
included:**/*.java
excluded:src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/main/test, src/test/resources
```

After "Update Project" through Maven configuration here is the resulted change in configuration:

```
included:**/*.java
excluded:(None)
```

Which configuration, Maven (pom.xml) or Spring configuration, is responsible for this change in project structure? Which settings/configuration will guide to retain it back to its initial project structure.

(Short note: Maven and Spring Nature "Enabled" on the project. Symbol 'S' and 'M' were displaying on the project folder)

Comment: All the project java class files were removed from the project src/ folder when followed this step: Java Build Path-->sources-->src/main/java-->remove. But internally saved intact in workspace. For a moment, I saw the java class files were not seen in the project src/ folder as i required but they were retained back by following the below steps: sources--> add folder --> select source folder --> by selecting tick mark in the check box of src/main/java. Even though after this exercise, by Maven Update Project, unable to get initial project structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pom.xml file configuration is associated with this issue. Because of the below code in pom.xml it is copying all java source files to src/ folder. By changing this, it will fix the project structure with source folder.

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
   <resource>
       <directory>src</directory>
       <excludes>
           <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
       </excludes>
   </resource>
</resources>
</build>
```

replace this code with the below code:

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
   <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
       <excludes>
           <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
       </excludes>
   </resource>
</resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps project --> right click --> properties -->:

```
Java Build Path --> sources --> src --> Delete
src/main/java --> edit --> output folder: <project name>/target/classes
src/main/java --> edit --> included: **/*.java
src/main/java --> edit --> excluded: (None)
```

Those steps has removed src/ folder and made src/main/java as the base source folder with java class source files, with this got back the initial project structure.

Comment: When the project structure is checked in Project Explorer in STS, still src/ folder with java class files can be viewed. Will there be any affect on execution of the project with both folder src/ and src/main/java contains java source class files, some workout has to be done on this.